# Laravel Issue with Artisan when using different computer on NAS to run terminal

Tags: laravel, debugging

I have my code on a local NAS at home. When I run

`php artisan serve`

on terminal in my desktop computer, the application starts up no problem.

However, when I am on my laptop, and I want to run the server, the following part just runs endlessly and doesn't proceed:..

`Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000`

The reason I'm asking here is I am having a hard time knowing how to troubleshoot this issue.

The error I'm receiving when I try to load the app URL from my laptop while the terminal is still in 'starting' mode is..

````
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = ZbOqp13BZNRquGtmG0Vi2XNHGWi3WDMJxW4ZYYCK limit 1)```
````

Also, my database.php in the config folder under mysql looks like this:

````
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '33060'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],```
````

I don't see this issue mentioned on SO previously, and would appreciate ideas on how to troubleshoot this. Ideally I should be able to connect to the server fine even if I am on another computer in the same network.

Troubleshooting tips appreciated.

My .env for the database is:

````
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret```
````

Comment: It's not clear in your question where your MySQL is running, if locally or at the NAS. Also, please check the `.env` file, it should contain your DB_* variables, they should be pointing to your MySQL instance. If you are connecting the NAS MySQL make sure to have the ports and firewall properly configured, including the bind_address of MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I just updated the question to include the .env variables. It seems to be the same as in the config configuration. I wonder how I can see where the MySQL is running?

Comment: If you are simply running the php command after checking out your projects, for sure its not running on the same machine, usually the MySQL is loaded separately via Sail or any other environment tool. If you are using homestead to develop check https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead. Note that `artisan serve` only starts the PHP handling software, not the DB services.

Comment: so the MySQL is meant to be running on the local computer, and not on the NAS folder that contains the code?

Comment: MySQL is a separate application, it's not really correct to say it runs at the NAS folder. Usually, it runs at port 3306. Note that your NAS probably has a ton of other things running at the same time, and something else might be using it. I suggest googling how to install MySQL at your NAS specific model. You can use docker, install it manually, or even use sqlite instead of MySQL to solve your issue.